# My range for loop doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have to print out the size of the vector and all the contents inside it.  But my for loop doesnt iterate, it doesn't go up by one but instead stays at the value 0 for the whole loop.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

  vector<int> v2(10);
      for( auto i : v2)
      {
          if( i == 0 )
          {
             std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;
          }

         std::cout << "Element value " << (i) << " is " << v2[i] << std::endl;
      }
```

So I only want to print the size once, at the start. Then print out each element value which I know will be 0 by default. But it just prints out "Element value 0 is 0" 9 times.

Comment: `i` is not an index, it's an element.

Comment: In a range-based for-loop over a vector, `i` does not represent an index, but the actual element within the vector.

Comment: ...and that can be found easily by reading about how range-based for loops work. **Use Google.**

Comment: @user3216729 please run at least yourself your code. it can not print 9 times "Element value 0 is 0" because the vector has 10 elements.

Comment: Where do you put stuff in the vector?

Answer (score 0):

If you want at first to print out the size of the vector then place this output statement before the range based for statement

```
std::vector<int> v2(10);

std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;

size_t i = 0;
for ( auto x : v2 )
{
     std::cout << "Element value " << i++ << " is " << x << std::endl;
}
```

But if you are using a count then it would be better to use the ordinary for statement

```
std::vector<int> v2(10);

std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;

for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++ )
{
     std::cout << "Element value " << i << " is " << v2[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that you want to **treat the first element differently**. This does not work with range-based `for` loops out of the box. You have two options:

1. Use an extra variable to remember whether the first iteration was made.
2. Use a traditional loop, using an index variable or an iterator.

Example for 1:

```
bool first_iteration = true;
for( auto i : v2)
{
    if (first_iteration)
    {
       std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;
       first_iteration = false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Example for 2:

```
for (auto iter = v2.begin(); iter != v2.end(); ++iter)
{
    if (iter == v2.begin())
    {
       std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;
    }

    // ...
 }
```